# Different dll's version for projects in a solution

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a big solution for a desktop application with a bunch of projects in it. There is one which uses an old version of MySql dll. I cannot replace it with a newer one, because it's not fully compatible and I can't afford any unexpected behavior (a bunch of clients use this software).

Recently I created a new project which uses nhibernate (by nuget) with the latest MySql. I want to little by little start using database via this project. The problem is that even though it compiles successfully it throws exceptions when I run it. (Main project which references to both mentioned above cannot find one of the MySql dlls).

I cannot just replace the old database access projects right now, because it's referenced in a few hundred/thousend places.

What's the best way to go?

Comment: Which assembly is the main project saying it can't find?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud MySql.Data as far as I remember (don't have access to the code right now)

Comment: Did you check the project Post/Pre build events?